# Concatenation of All Possible Combinations of Files with Python

Tags: python, concatenation

I'll preface this by admitting I'm very new to Python.  I have a directory of files that I would like to see all the possible combinations.  I've located a script that can concatenate one set list of files but I would like to see all the possible combinations of these files have them concatenated and save them as a jpg.  To make things more complicated I have two specific files that I always want at the beginning of all combinations and one specific file that I always want at the end.

Slapping some code I found from a similar question together I've come up with the below which obviously isn't going to to cut it.

```
files = ['File1.txt', 'Filet2.txt']

with open('CombinedFile.jpg', 'w') as result:
        for file_ in files:
            for line in open(file_, 'r'):
                result.write(line)
```

EDIT:  I realized I may not have articulated the question well enough I would like to combine the contents of the file per below:

Combine:

> File1.txt Contents
>
> File2.txt Contents
>
> File3.txt Contents

Output Result:

> CombinationFile.jpg

And then again with the files in different order until all possible combinations have been run.

Comment: Do you already have a list of all the filenames?

Comment: When you say "save them as a jpg", do you mean "a text file containing text that happens to have the .jpg extension", or "a jpg file, which can be viewed as an image, which contains a visual representation of the contents of the given files"?

Comment: If it's the latter, this post might work better if separated into multiple posts: 1, "how do I get all possible combinations of a sequence of items?", 2, "how do I get the concatenated contents of a sequence of files?" and 3, "How do I draw text on an image and save it as a jpg?"

Comment: In any case, check out [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.permutations).

Comment: Sorry I should have been a bit more specific the content of the text files is jpg hex data that I'm trying to brute force back into a viewable image.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean `permutation` saying `combination`:

```
import itertools

files = ['File1.txt', 'File2.txt', 'File3.txt']

it = itertools.permutations(files, len(files))

for x in it:
     print x
```

result

```
('File1.txt', 'File2.txt', 'File3.txt')
('File1.txt', 'Filt3.txt', 'File2.txt')
('File2.txt', 'File1.txt', 'File3.txt')
('File2.txt', 'File3.txt', 'File1.txt')
('File3.txt', 'File1.txt', 'File2.txt')
('File3.txt', 'File2.txt', 'File1.txt')
```

Comment: A `Filet` instead of a `File`? :)

Comment: In comments he said `1, "how do I get all possible combinations of a sequence of items?"`

Comment: But SO said `I've located a script that can concatenate one set list of files but I would like to see all the possible combinations of these files` - so more importat for SO is to get combinations of filenames.

Comment: @ Christian Berendt - in question is `files = ['File1.txt', 'Filet2.txt']` and I used it so I had `Filet` :)